# ngx bootstrap installation .... need help to understand wht the error is about

Tags: ngx-bootstrap

im running the install cmd for ngx-bootstrap `npm install ngx-bootstrap --save`
 but i get the following errors

```
npm ERR! request to https://registry.npmjs.org/ngx-bootstrap failed, reason: Hostname/IP doesn't match certificate's altnames: "Host: registry.npmjs.org. is not in the cert's altnames: DNS:a.sni.fastly.net, DNS:a.sni.global-ssl.fastly.net

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\user1\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-09-01T13_52_56_500Z-debug.log
```

I would like to know what could be the issue

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52128212/npm-not-installing-package-hostname-ip-doesnt-match-certificates-altnames

Answer (score 0):

run `npm config set strict-ssl false`
and re-run `npm install ngx-bootstrap --save`