# Can't install redux & react-redux

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux, expo

I am using these commands to install **redux**:

```
npm install redux
npm install --save redux
npm install --save redux --force
```

The same commands to install **react-redux** with replacing **redux** in the above commands.

```
npm install react-redux
npm install --save react-redux
npm install --save react-redux --force
```

But the issue is, it installs normally in Windows C Directory and when I import and use it:

```
import {bindActionCreators,createStore, applyMiddleware} from 'redux'
import {connect, Provider } from 'react-redux'
```

It Displays the Following Error:

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'react-redux'
```

Then, I stop the Server and install it in Project Directory it displays the Following Error.

```
npm WARN using --force Recommended protections disabled.
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path E:\Kashif Iftikhar\Coding\Projects\Latest Projects\React Native\Plantonics\node_modules\grpc
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --library=static_library
npm ERR! Failed to execute 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --library=static_library --module=E:\Kashif Iftikhar\University\FYP\Code\React Native\Plantonics\node_modules\grpc\src\node\extension_binary\node-v88-win32-x64-unknown\grpc_node.node --module_name=grpc_node --module_path=E:\Kashif Iftikhar\Coding\Projects\Latest Projects\React Native\Plantonics\node_modules\grpc\src\node\extension_binary\node-v88-win32-x64-unknown --napi_version=7 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v88' (1)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info using node-pre-gyp@0.14.0
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info using node@15.11.0 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp WARN Using needle for node-pre-gyp https download
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info check checked for "E:\Kashif Iftikhar\Coding\Projects\Latest Projects\React Native\Plantonics\node_modules\grpc\src\node\extension_binary\node-v88-win32-x64-unknown\grpc_node.node" (not found)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp http GET https://node-precompiled-binaries.grpc.io/grpc/v1.24.2/node-v88-win32-x64-unknown.tar.gz
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp http 404 https://node-precompiled-binaries.grpc.io/grpc/v1.24.2/node-v88-win32-x64-unknown.tar.gz
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp WARN Tried to download(404): https://node-precompiled-binaries.grpc.io/grpc/v1.24.2/node-v88-win32-x64-unknown.tar.gz
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not found for grpc@1.24.2 and node@15.11.0 (node-v88 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp http 404 status code downloading tarball https://node-precompiled-binaries.grpc.io/grpc/v1.24.2/node-v88-win32-x64-unknown.tar.gz
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@7.1.2
npm ERR! gyp info using node@15.11.0 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! gyp info ok
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@7.1.2
npm ERR! gyp info using node@15.11.0 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! gyp info find Python using Python version 3.8.5 found at "C:\Users\Qasim Iftikhar\anaconda3\python.exe"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS msvs_version not set from command line or npm config
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS VCINSTALLDIR not set, not running in VS Command Prompt
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS could not use PowerShell to find Visual Studio 2017 or newer, try re-running with '--loglevel silly' for more details
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS looking for Visual Studio 2015
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS - not found
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS not looking for VS2013 as it is only supported up to Node.js 8
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS You need to install the latest version of Visual Studio
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS including the "Desktop development with C++" workload.
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS For more information consult the documentation at:
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#on-windows
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: Could not find any Visual Studio installation to use
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at VisualStudioFinder.fail (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:121:47)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:74:16
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at VisualStudioFinder.findVisualStudio2013 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:351:14)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:70:14
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:372:16
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\util.js:54:7
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\util.js:33:16
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (node:child_process:333:5)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:378:20)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1067:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.10240
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "configure" "--fallback-to-build" "--library=static_library" "--module=E:\\Kashif Iftikhar\\Coding\\Projects\\Latest Projects\\React Native\\Plantonics\\node_modules\\grpc\\src\\node\\extension_binary\\node-v88-win32-x64-unknown\\grpc_node.node" "--module_name=grpc_node" "--module_path=E:\\Kashif Iftikhar\\Coding\\Projects\\Latest Projects\\React Native\\Plantonics\\node_modules\\grpc\\src\\node\\extension_binary\\node-v88-win32-x64-unknown" "--napi_version=7" "--node_abi_napi=napi" "--napi_build_version=0" "--node_napi_label=node-v88"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd E:\Kashif Iftikhar\Coding\Projects\Latest Projects\React Native\Plantonics\node_modules\grpc
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v15.11.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v7.1.2
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! build error
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --library=static_library --module=E:\Kashif Iftikhar\Coding\Projects\Latest Projects\React Native\Plantonics\node_modules\grpc\src\node\extension_binary\node-v88-win32-x64-unknown\grpc_node.node --module_name=grpc_node --module_path=E:\Kashif Iftikhar\Coding\Projects\Latest Projects\React Native\Plantonics\node_modules\grpc\src\node\extension_binary\node-v88-win32-x64-unknown --napi_version=7 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v88' (1)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (E:\Kashif Iftikhar\Coding\Projects\Latest Projects\React Native\Plantonics\node_modules\grpc\node_modules\node-pre-gyp\lib\util\compile.js:83:29)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:378:20)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1067:16)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:301:5)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.10240
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "E:\\Kashif Iftikhar\\Coding\\Projects\\Latest Projects\\React Native\\Plantonics\\node_modules\\grpc\\node_modules\\node-pre-gyp\\bin\\node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build" "--library=static_library"
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd E:\Kashif Iftikhar\Coding\Projects\Latest Projects\React Native\Plantonics\node_modules\grpc
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v15.11.0
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.14.0
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Qasim Iftikhar\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-03-26T06_53_12_689Z-debug.log
```

Also there is no `"lodash-es": "~4.0.0"` in my Package.json file.

**Note:** I am Building App with **Expo CLI** and just imported Redux to fetch data from **Google Firebase**.

Comment: Use "npm install react-redux" for installing redux

Comment: As I described above, I have used this `npm install react-redux ` with replacing `npm install redux`. And also different other commands like `--save` and `--force`.

Comment: are you behind a vpn or dns?

Comment: @JuniusL. `DNS`.

Comment: your dns doesn't resolve to the global npm registry and it tries to find the module within your network.

Comment: @JuniusL. Do you know how to solve this?

Comment: This might help in that case https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52128212/npm-not-installing-package-hostname-ip-address-doesnt-match-certificates-altn

Answer (score 0):

Remove node_modules and reinstall, or try use yarn

```sh
rm -rf node_modules/ && npm install
```

Comment: Which module to remove?

Comment: Remove all of them. Delete the node_modules folder，then  reinstall